# Is it possible to do list manipulation using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, list

This may be a stupid question but I've always used linq to select items.

But i wish to know if it possible to do the following simple task using its keywords.

```
List<OrdersInfo> ordersList
.
.
.
foreach(OrdersInfo OI in ordersList)
        if(OI.TYPE == "P")
            OI.TYPE = "Project";
        else
        OI.TYPE = "Support";
```

Comment: LINQ is meant to be mutation-free. If you want to manipulate, use `foreach`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [LINQ(Language-Integrated Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb397926.aspx) is a *query* language and it really shines in consise *query definition*, but not always good in that too (speed and/or memory concerns).

If you want to modify collection, stay with the way you already do that.

Comment: Tigran, I do agree with most part of your answer, but You can modify the list using LINQ. (Although shouldn't)

Answer (score 6):

You can use ForEach method of List class.

```
ordersList.ForEach(oi => oi.TYPE = oi.TYPE == "P" ? "Project" : "Support" );
```

If you want have ForEach method in IEnumerable type you can create your own ForEach extension

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> en, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(T item in en)
    {
        action(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is for querying collection, For modification your current loop is more readable and better approach, but if you want LINQ option then:

If `OrderInfo` is a class (reference type), then you can modify the properties of the object, (You **can't** assign them null or a new references).

```
var ordersList = new List<OrdersInfo>();
ordersList.Add(new OrdersInfo() { TYPE = "P" });
ordersList.Add(new OrdersInfo() { TYPE = "S" });
ordersList.Add(new OrdersInfo() { TYPE = "P" });
ordersList.Select(r => (r.TYPE == "P" ? r.TYPE = "Project" : r.TYPE = "Support")).ToList();
```

With Your class defined as:

```
class OrdersInfo
{
    public string TYPE { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the screenshot
[image]

***Interestingly I didn't assign the result back to `ordersList`***

Comment: Not sure about a syntactical mistake, probably the mistake is showing somebody how to do this using LINQ?

Comment: @sixlettervariables, syntatically its correct, I actually tested it in VS. I agree it shouldn't be done through LINQ and I have that as well in the start of my answer, but being downvoted for showing if it is possible... hmm . thats new for me :)

Comment: Folks get downvoted all the time for code which "works" but has XSS/SQL injection problems, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bwabdf9z.aspx) is not a Linq solution, but it looks like it is:

```
ordersList.ForEach(OI => OI.TYPE = OI.TYPE == "P" ? "Project" : "Support");
```

Available ony on `List<T>` instance, not on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Sorry I don't have see your answer

Comment: We post at the same time, and we are here to help, not to compete :)

Comment: I don't understand the duplicate OI.TYPE

Comment: Yes it's right =) If @AngelicCore wish have a ForEach method in IEnumerable type he/she can create his own ForEach extension method

Comment: @AngelicCore Look at this answer, it is called a ternary operator : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c/16450#16450