# updating multiple records in database with linq to sql without loop, is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

ok, let say i want to update multiple rows in database at once, without looping, if we do it with loop, it might look like this :

```
var products = (from prod in context.Products
               where prod.ProductCategoryID == myProductID
               select prod).ToList();


// modify each object
foreach (var product in products)
{
    product.PhoneNumber = ???;
    product.Name = ???;
    product.Address = ???;
}


context.SubmitChanges();
```

is there better way to do this? without doing any loop? consider me as a beginner on linq, so if there is some better way, it would be great if you provide me some example, thanks in advance.

Comment: Parallel.For may be what your looking for - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713.aspx

Comment: Habib provides the answer. The only improvement I see is removing the ToList but that is off topic.

Comment: is n't everyone free to give their opinion? to help other have a better understanding, i wonder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LINQ` is for quering records. Your current `foreach` loop is more readable and if you try other approach then it will use loop  internally.

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16191448/961113) which modifies the collection using LINQ, but it is not the recommended way.

Comment: In what i have heard about, i guess EF or Linq to SQL does not support bulk operations. Please suggest.

Comment: @saravanan, that is right. For example in LINQ to SQL we have `InsertAllOnSubmit` but internally it uses a loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this info. I have learnt this now.

Comment: hello @habib, thx for your response, well what i get from your explaination is most likely linq will always do loop?

Comment: @HendraLim, yes LINQ internally uses loop for most of the queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that line:

```
var products = (from prod in context.Products
                where prod.ProductCategoryID == myProductID
                select new Product(prod.PhoneNumber.ToLower(), prod.Name.ToUpper(), prod.Address.Trim()).ToList();
```

If you wanna change your products directly in your context object : make a specific function in Products class only. It will simply well designed.

```
 (from prod in context.Products
  where prod.ProductCategoryID == myProductID
  select prod.MakeChange(myPhoneNumber, myName, myAddress);
```

As you can call that line of code, prod should be changed along the LINQ query.