# How to update a property for a specific element of an IEnumerable List in C#

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have an `IEnumerable` list, `IEnumerable<SortElement>` sorts;

I am updating its property as:

```
sorts.Where(a => a.DisplayName.ToLower() == "abc")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(sl => sl.DisplayName = "Testing");
```

But it does not change the property for that specific element.

Comment: Is SortElement a struct?

Answer (score 6):

Change `"ABC"` to `"abc"`. Your condition will never be met. You can also change `.ToLower()` to `.ToUpper()`.

I would do some thing like this:

```
foreach(var e in sorts.Where(a => a.DisplayName.ToLower() == "abc"))
   e.DisplayName = "Testing";
```

Because your code in fact executes 2 loops, that's not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ is better for querying, it is not a good option for modification.

You can modify the list items like:

```
foreach (var item in sorts)
{
    if (item.DisplayName.Equals("abc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        item.DisplayName = "Testing";
    }
}
```

OR

```
foreach (var item in 
    sorts.Where(r=> r.DisplayName.Equals("abc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
        item.DisplayName = "Testing";
}
```

Use [string.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx) overload for case insenstive comparison.

There is one pure LINQ way of doing it but please don't. LINQ is for querying, not for modification. It should only work if `SortElement` is a class, not a struct, because of reference type passed to lambda.

```
sorts.Select(r => r.DisplayName.Equals("abc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                ? r.DisplayName = "Testing"
                : r.DisplayName ).ToList();
```

The above would work, even without assigning the result back to `sorts`. But it should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using in place update - `Select` and `ToList` in conjuction.

In `Select` change the filtered list to desired value and do `ToList` in order to evaluate the select immediately due to lazy evaluation -

```
sorts.Where(a => a.DisplayName.ToUpper() == "ABC")
    .Select(sl => sl.DisplayName = "Testing").ToList();
```

Comment: This will create a new list with only those elements which are selected from the criteria. OP is looking for modification in original list.

Comment: This will indeed modify the original list. Have you give it a try? In `Select` query i update the displayName in case you missed it.

Comment: you are right. This will modify the original list, since reference will be modified later.

Comment: But I have been [downvoted for similar response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191342/is-it-possible-to-do-list-manipulation-using-linq/16191448#16191448) :).